# TableViewCell with 3 buttons with images and tags

Tags: uitableview, uibutton

I am trying to create a tableView that has 3 Custom buttons and tags, i have 12 images which equates to 4 rows of 3 buttons. Now the code as is now shows the first 3 images in  all the rows, i want all 12 images in all 12 buttons.

So each button needs to have a image and a tag which is different from the others.

Can some one help me create this, here is my code so far
**edit for formatting**

```
(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

}


btnImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"dog1.png",@"dog2.png",@"dog3.png",@"dog4.png",@"dog5.png",@"dog6.png"
             @"dog7.png",@"dog8.png",@"dog9.png",@"dog10.png",@"dog11.png",@"dog12.png",nil];

for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    //position the UiButtons in the scrollView
    CGRect frame = CGRectMake((i*100) + 35, 35, 45, 45);

    //Create the UIbuttons
    UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
    [button setTag:i];
    [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    button.frame = frame;
    button.clipsToBounds = NO;
    button.contentMode = UIViewContentModeCenter;


    //Add images to the button
    UIImage *btnImg = [UIImage imageNamed:[btnImages objectAtIndex:i]];
    [button setBackgroundImage:btnImg forState:UIControlStateNormal];
     [cell.contentView addSubview:button];   
}

return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

just put the row

```
btnImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithObjects:@"dog1.png",@"dog2.png",@"dog3.png",@"dog4.png",@"dog5.png",@"dog6.png"
         @"dog7.png",@"dog8.png",@"dog9.png",@"dog10.png",@"dog11.png",@"dog12.png",nil];
```

inside the method `viewDidLoad:`